# what does $# accept as input in perl?

Tags: perl

I have had this question for a while.

Assuming I have a simple array,

```
    my @arr;
    foreach my $i (0..$#arr){
        print "\$arr[$i] = '$arr[$i]'\n";
    }
```

$#arr simply returns the last index of the array

however, what happens if I want to use it for something more complex like?:

```
   foreach my $i (0..$#@{$someHash{$}[$b]{$c}});
```

sure, I can write it as

```
   foreach my $i (0..(scalar(@{$someHash{$}[$b]{$c}})-1));
```

But that just makes the code even more complex.

So my question is, can the $# be used for anything else other than a simple array( references, a list returned from a function call, etc...) and if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you want:

```
for my $i (0..$#{$some_hash{$a}[$b]{$c}}) { ... }
```

If possible, though, I generally prefer

```
for my $value (@{ $some_hash{$a}[$b]{$c} }) { ... }
```

an index value is rarely as useful as the value stored in the array. Typically, if I need both, I add a counter instead:

```
my $i = 0;
for my $value (@{ $some_hash{$a}[$b]{$c} }) { ... } continue { $i++ }
```

and for clarity, I will also pre-assign the complex variable in the loop:

```
my $i = 0;
my $widget_list = $some_hash{$a}[$b]{$c};
for my $value (@{ $widget_list }) { ... } continue { $i++ }
```

Just because you can do some things in one line in Perl doesn't necessarily mean you should.

Comment: The `for { } continue { }` construct is a pretty slick way of handling the index increment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done:

```
sub foo {
    return { 'bar' => { 'array' => [ 'qux', [qw/ has three elements /] ] } };
}

print $#{ foo->{'bar'}->{'array'}->[1] };    # 2
```

When writing such code, my thought process is: get to the array with the `@{}` syntax and then replace `@` with `$#`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's

```
$#array
```

for an array, it's

```
$#{ $array_ref }
```

for a reference. Of course, it can be any expression that returns an array reference, so you want the following:

```
$#{ $someHash{$}[$b]{$c} }
```

See [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)